# Circumradius of a tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I put the following formula for the circumradius of a tetrahedron on the Wikipedia page on the tetrahedron, but it was deleted for lack of a citation.  Does anyone have a reference for it?

Here, $a,b,c$ are three edges that meet at a point; $A,B,C$ are the opposite edges; and $V$ is the volume of the tetrahedron.
$$R = \frac{\sqrt{(aA+bB+cC)(aA+bB-cC)(aA-bB+cC)(-aA+bB+cC)}}{24V}$$

Comment: I happen to use the formula in my note ["Heron-like Hedronometric Results for Tetrahedral Volume" (PDF)](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/mathdocs/Heron-like-Results-for-Tetrahedral-Volume.pdf) (the very last line!), but I don't provide a justification for it. (As I recall, I derived it from [MathWorld's coordinate-based formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumsphere.html) via a bunch of symbol-crunching with *Mathematica*.)

Comment: How about *publishing* this as a note in some expository journal, then citing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a result by [A. L. Crelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/August_Leopold_Crelle). It first? appeared in

- Crelle, A. L. "Einige Bemerkungen über die dreiseitige Pyramide." Sammlung mathematischer Aufsätze u. Bemerkungen 1, 105-132, 1821.
  (<strike>an online copy is available on [archive.org](https://www.archive.org/details/sammlungmathemat01cre)</strike>)

The statement appears at page 117 (item 186) and the proof is one or two pages around that. Since the article is in German and I don't speak German, I don't know where the proof exactly starts.

Another English reference is

- I. Todhunter, "Spherical Trigonometry: For the Use of Colleges and Schools" (1886)
  (online copies are available under Project Gutenberg 
  [1](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770) and archive.org
  [2](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigon03todhgoog),
  [3](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigono00todhrich),
  [4](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigono19770gut)
  ).

The material is covered at page 129 ( Art. 163 ).

Comment: Thanks for that.

Comment: There are also several copies of Todhunter's book on archive.org: [1](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigon03todhgoog), [2](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigono00todhrich), [3](https://archive.org/details/sphericaltrigono19770gut).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut  Thanks for the links. Since Todhunter's book is also available on amazon. In the worst case, I can always point it to that.

Comment: Well, [Isaac Todhunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Todhunter) died in 1884, so I don't think there is any risk of copyright infringement (I would not have given the links otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

In "An Open Problem on Metric Invariants of Tetrahedra" (citation below), Lu Yang and Zhenbing Zeng mention matter-of-factly that the circumradius $R$ satisfies

$$R^2 = -\frac{M_5}{2 M_0}$$

where $M_0$ is the [Cayley-Menger determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html), and where $M_5$ is the principal minor determinant obtained by deleting the $5$th row and column of $M_0$.
That is, in the notation of OP, 
$$\begin{align}
M_0 := \left|\begin{array}{ccccc}
  0 & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 & 1 \\
a^2 &   0 & C^2 & B^2 & 1 \\
b^2 & C^2 &   0 & A^2 & 1 \\
c^2 & B^2 & A^2 &   0 & 1 \\
  1 &   1 &   1 &   1 & 0 
\end{array}\right| &= 288 V^2 \\[8pt]
M_5 := \left|\begin{array}{cccc}
  0 & a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
a^2 &   0 & C^2 & B^2 \\
b^2 & C^2 &   0 & A^2 \\
c^2 & B^2 & A^2 &   0 \\
\end{array}\right| 
&= \begin{array}{c}
-(a A + b B + c C)(-a A + b B + c C) \\
\cdot(a A - b B + c C)(a A + b B - c C) 
\end{array}
\end{align}$$
which gives the relation OP mentions.

I suspect that the relation should appear in a comprehensive reference of Cayley-Menger lore, but my cursory web search has been fruitless.

---

Here's the citation information I have for the Yang-Zeng note:

Lu Yang and Zhenbing Zeng, *An open problem on metric invariants of tetrahedra, Proceedings of the 2005 international symposium on Symbolic and algebraic computation (ISSAC ’05).* ACM, New York, NY, USA, 362-364. DOI=10.1145/1073884.1073934 http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1073884.1073934

A PDF of the paper containing the note appears to be available from ResearchGate: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221563984_An_open_problem_on_metric_invariants_of_tetrahedra

Comment: Thanks.  I'll leave it for a day or two in case there is a more specific reference to it.