# Volume of a sphere enclosing six tetrahedron edges

Tags: 3d, spheres

Six edge lengths of a tetrahedron  $ (a,b,c,p,q,r)  $ are given.

- What relation should be there in order that a tetrahedron  can be enclosed among the edge side lengths?
- What is the volume $V$ of the tetrahedron?  Is it like $V= \frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\sqrt{abcpqr}?$  The constant is obtained from a regular tetrahedronal special case.
- What is the volume of the circumscribing sphere? Is it
  like$$ \frac{\pi ~ 64 \sqrt 2}{243 \sqrt 3} \cdot \sqrt{abcpqr}~?$$ The constant is obtained similarly.

Logic is that if any edge length vanishes, then the volumes should also vanish.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I will assume $p,q,r$ corresponds to edges opposite to $a,b,c$. They are realizable as edge lengths of tetrahedron iff 1) the faces satisfy triangle inequalities AND 2) the corr Cayler Menger determinant is positive. see refs in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/513098). The volume can be computed using the CM determinant. The formula for circumradius can be found in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2820212)

Comment: Thanks@ achille hui for so many links/references. Actually verified given probable guess cases to be incorrect before posting  itself. Often wonder about guessing... how generalizations are done from particular cases if not using prior knowledge ! :)